# Mouse click event in qt 3.0.3

Tags: qt

Mouse button clicki am trying to create an automatic mouse click event at a particular co ordinate.

This source code moves the mouse pointer to the co ordinate region but it is not clicking.

please help me to solve this problem or suggest any new idea to automate mouse click event.

Note: i am using QT 3.0.3

```
 void mMouseClickFunction() 
  { 

   QWidget *d = QApplication::desktop()->screen(); 
   int w=d->width(); // returns desktop width 
   int h=d->height(); 
   printf("w=%d\nh=%d\n",w,h); 
   int x,y; 
   printf("Enter the points...\n"); 
   scanf("%d%d",&x,&y); 
   QApplication::desktop()->cursor().setPos(x,y); 
   QPoint pt(x,y); 
    std::cout << pt.x() << " " << pt.y() << std::endl; 
   QMouseEvent *e = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pt,Qt::LeftButton, 0); 
   QApplication::sendEvent(d, e); 
   std::cout << "in contentsMousePressEvent"<< e->x() << " " << e->y() << std::endl; 
   QMouseEvent *p = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pt,Qt::LeftButton, 0); 
   QApplication::sendEvent(d, p); 
   std::cout << "in contentsMouseReleaseEvent"<< p->x() << " " << p->y() << std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QApplication::sendEvent` sends an event internal to the QApplication, not a system wide event.  You probably need to be system specific to send out an event like that.  Here is the function call for windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

But even with that kind of call, you will be limited to certain windows, unless you have UIAccess to be true, and your program is a signed application located in the right part of the harddrive.

EDIT: Here is a page that has some examples for sending input in Linux:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/simulating-a-mouse-click-594576/

Hope that helps.

Comment: i need the same help in linux envirnomet not windows thanks for your suggestion.....please help me to solve it

Comment: i am already implemented the same as like above mentioned linux link

Comment: but the problem is it is supporting for X86 artitech, but not cross compilation things

Comment: i need the same for cross compilation provide me suggestions pls

Comment: so do you mean making it work on 32 bit linux and on 64 bit linux?  Using Qt makes it easy to recompile for different OS's, and different architectures.  You still need to compile it.  At least for windows, you can run win32 apps on 64 bit architectures.  For distribution to lots of linux setups, you either need to provide the sources, and let each person compile it themselves, or you need to make a distribution that has been compiled for common hardware setups.

Comment: Below is test.cpp #include <X11/Xlib.h> #include<stdio.h> #include<unistd.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <string.h> #include <unistd.h> int main(int argc, char** argv) { int Xco,Yco; Display* display = XOpenDisplay(0); Window root =DefaultRootWindow(display); Xco=atoi(argv[1]); Yco=atoi(argv[2]); XWarpPointer(display, None, root, 0, 0, 0, 0, Xco, Yco); XCloseDisplay(display); return 0; } we all know that compilation in x86 would be g++ -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 test test.cpp But how to compile the same file for cross compilation???? Please anyone suggest me a solution to solve the problem